# Get all user's paperclip avatar url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails 5 API and I am using paperclip to upload user's avatar. I have an index page of all users where I have to list all the users. I need a way to display all the users avatar

`@user.avatar.url` can be used to get one user's avatar.

I could use

```
@users.each do |user|
    @avatar.push(user.avatar.url)
end
```

Is there another way?
Also, can I save the URL into an image field using a callback like `after_save` or `after_update` during user sign up?

Comment: Can you please clear the question what exactly you want

Comment: what's the problem with `@user.avatar.url` or you just want all avatars in one variable?

Comment: I want all the users avatar in one variable so that I can pass it as json

Answer (score 1):

Just push them in a hash

```
@avatars = {} 
@users.each{ |user| { @avatars[user.id] = user.avatar.url }
```

Now you can access users avatar using

```
@avatars[user_id] # This will return you the avatar
```

Comment: Is there a way we can set the image url in user model after saving avatar using callback method